# get json data back from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

my question is: How can my php script send json type data
and received back into the success or complete function?

I was trying to get [this](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/) chatfunction to work on my website
Because it diddn't work, I created a minimized portion off the code to check
if it had something to do with the json method.

I only tested if I could get a sessionname back after the phpscript was proccessed
What I get back is "undefined" instead of "johndoe".

I have no idea what could be the problem.
Obviously, the script has worked fine for others, if you see the comments on the creators page.

this is my testingcode

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['username'] = "johndoe" ;// Must be already set
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#testjson").click(function(e){
 startJsonSession();

    return false;
    });


function startJsonSession(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: "jsontest.php?action=startjson",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(data) {
            username = data.username;
            alert(username);
        }

    });
}


}); 
</script>

<?php
//the php script

if ($_GET['action'] == "startjson") { startjsonSession(); } 



function startjsonSession() {
    $items = '';


    /*if (!empty($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'] as $chatbox => $void) {
            $items .= chatBoxSession($chatbox);
        }
    }


    if ($items != '') {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }*/

header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
        "username": "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>",
        "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
}

<?php


    exit(0);
}

?>
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2):

Richard, you should look into the [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/json_encode) function in PHP. It will convert your array to JSON quickly, and keep you from having to deal with the smaller nuances of JSON syntax with large amounts of data.

---

Update: Modified Code

```
<?php

    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = "johndoe" ;// Must be already set
    
?>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#testjson").click(function(e){
        startJsonSession();
        return false;
    });
         
    function startJsonSession(){  
        $.ajax({
            url: "jsontest.php?action=startjson",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data) {
                username = data.username;
                alert(username);
            }
        
        });
    }
                  
}); 
</script>
    
<?php
    
    if ($_GET['action'] == "startjson") { 
        startjsonSession(); 
    } 
    
    function startjsonSession() {
        $items = '';
    
        print json_encode(array(
            "username" => "bob",
            "items" => array(
                "item1" => "sandwich",
                "item2" => "applejuice"
            )
        ));
    }
?>
```

Comment: yes, I already looked into that a bit
but before I have to change the creators code, I was wondering if there could be something else going on that causes this.
I really don't look forward to change his code because I do not completely understand it. With the heredoc syntax and more

Comment: Try a JSON format like this: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5} - So your code would be {"username": "bob","items": "apples"} (Go ahead and leave the hard-coded values for testing)

Comment: Also, pull that header() method out for now - comment it out.

Comment: One second...your formatting has me a bit confused. Let me clean it up on my screen and take a second look...

Comment: Richard, I made some changes - it works locally for me. Check my post for updated code.

Comment: I saw you used the php function. I believe you when you say it works, but could you take a look at the authors code. I commented it out on my testpage sourcecode for you to look at. What I am trying to say is, am I going to get into a lot off trouble if I ajust this code with your method, because he uses heredoc, etc