# Dynamiclly change element CSS style using Ajax + JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

To simplify the question let's say I have a group of checkboxes (if selected - a specific style applied) and a href link.

```
<input type=checkbox  style="color:#0f0; background:#0f0; border:1px solid;" name=CHKB_3D unchecked>
<span id=CHKB_3D_span style="">3D Model</span><br/>
<input type=checkbox  name=CHKB_2D checked>
<span id=CHKB_2D_span style="color:#00D100;">2D Drawing</span><br/>
<input type=checkbox  name=CHKB_ST checked>
<span id=CHKB_ST_span style="color:#00D100;">Stack up</span><br/>
<a onclick="ajax_json_styling()" href="javascript:void(0);">click me to change style!</a>
```

[image]

The values of the checkboxes status are stored in the database.
The server (PHP) should decide which new color of checkbox label (span) I will have.
If not selected -> while, if selected -> green.

I have a working version of this behavior:
When I press href "save", I send ajax request to php, then on server side I write the new values of the status of the checkboxes. Then I create and echo a hidden DIV (later it's content will be eval() to apply new style) with specific styles that is based on current server data for checkboxes.
Then in Ajax I eval() the content of that hidden DIV and in that way apply new styling based on server data for checkboxes.

The challenge is to migrate from eval() to JSON+JSON.parse().
I know how to update multiple DIVs content with JSON (in Ajax I hardcode which DIV with a specific ID to update). But my situation is a bit different, because I need to decide on the server side which element to update (based on DB records).

I don't need hardcoded code in JS or JQuery on which element to apply styling, but the choice of which element should be done grammatically based on server side.

Can I do that with JSON?

Please provide a logic or a simple example on how I can do that.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Ajax + JSON = Ajaj? This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036028/get-json-data-back-from-ajax-call

Answer (score 2):

you can change it easily with jQuery:

```
$("#your-div-id").css("your-attribute", "your-value");
```

Comment: as I mentioned: I need to decide on the server side which element's style to be changed. In your code the element ID is hardcoded in JQuery

Comment: checkboxes are drawn by your browser, so you will have to determine their color on the client-side. you can either send the color value from the server and then set it using the above syntax, or decide on a color based on checkboxes' values on the client side (then you only need to save the values and do not have to wait for a server response to get the colors)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what format your data is in, but let's say it looks something like this:

```
{"checkboxes": {"CHKB_3D": "white", "CHKB_2D": "green", "CHKB_ST": "white"}}
```

Then your AJAX code would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/server/script.php',
    data: { /* stuff */ }
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for (var name in data.checkboxes) {
            $('#' + name + '_span').css('color', data.checkboxes[name]);
        }
    }
});
```