# Get JSON object from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spray-json

I'm new to `AJAX` and `javascript`. In my project, I have to get a `json` object in my `javascript` file. I've used `spray-json` and it shows me the json object in the url. `http://localhost:8081/all-modules`

```
{
  "status": "S1000",
  "description": "Success",
  "results": ["module1", "module2", "module3"]
}
```

My Ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/all-modules',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        complete: function(data){
            alert(data)
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
        }
```

It returns an alert `[object Object]`. What is the issue in here?

Comment: Try alerting `data.status`. I don't think there's an issue. You just cant alert an object

Comment: `alert` will implicitly call `toString` on `data`, which will be an object literal (how the JSON is parsed), and that value is "[object Object]"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036028/get-json-data-back-from-ajax-call

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(data) while displaying in alert as alert cannot display the object. It will convert object to string format.

Comment: That is already a JSON object

Answer (score 18):

Try the following;

```
var data = '{"name": "John","age": 30}';

var json = JSON.parse(data);

alert(json["name"]);
alert(json.name);
```

You can also check out this link: [How to access JSON object in JavaScript](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to see all the data in the JSON object, use `JSON.stringify`
Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more details

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

just console.log(data) you will see your object.

you can access your value by something like this

```
data.id //will give you id
```

it also depend on you json how you are creating check this out for explanation

```
// if it simply json then access it directly
//Example => {"id":1,"value":"APPLE"}
data.id; // will give you 1 

// if it json array then you need to iterate over array and then get value.
//Example => [{"id":1,"value":"APPLE"},{"id":2,"value":"MANGO"}] then
data[0].id;  // will give you 1
```

so your code will be like this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/all-modules',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    complete: function(data){
        alert(data.status);// S1000
        alert(data.description);// Success
        // for results you have to iterate because it is an array
        var len =  data.results.length;
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++ ){
            alert(data.results[i]);
        }
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try console.log() it will log on the console. alert doesnot displays the object.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/all-modules',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    complete: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is no longer in JSON format, it is a [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). You do not need to use function like jQuery.parseJSON anymore.

It is one common mistake for beginners.

If you want to see this Javascript Object, try `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

i think you just printing the object.Try someting like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/all-modules',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    complete: function(data){
        alert("status = "+data.status+"descripttion"+data.description);
    },
    success: function(data){
         alert("status = "+data.status+"descripttion"+data.description);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data[0].status;`. Your data are in an object now. At `console.log(data)` you can see that