# Getting json right in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to setup an analytics script in which I use json like this:

```
var visitors = [
    { date: "2014-01-11", value: 7 },
    { date: "2014-01-12", value: 2 },
    { date: "2014-01-13", value: 5 },
];
```

Now, I am getting my json through ajax from an php page like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON( "assets/ajax/flurry.php", { method: "ActiveUsers" } )
  .done(function( json ){

    var visitors = json; 
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json );

});
```

This produces this:

**JSON Data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**

My output from the php page look like this:

**[{"@date":"2015-01-14","@value":"948"},{"@date":"2015-01-15","@value":"4720"},{"@date":"2015-01-16","@value":"4989"},{"@date":"2015-01-17","@value":"5221"},{"@date":"2015-01-18","@value":"5658"},{"@date":"2015-01-19","@value":"5484"},{"@date":"2015-01-20","@value":"5508"},{"@date":"2015-01-21","@value":"5560"},{"@date":"2015-01-22","@value":"5576"},{"@date":"2015-01-23","@value":"5452"},{"@date":"2015-01-24","@value":"5524"},{"@date":"2015-01-25","@value":"5804"},{"@date":"2015-01-26","@value":"5714"},{"@date":"2015-01-27","@value":"5478"},{"@date":"2015-01-28","@value":"0"}]**

How do I get it to produce an javascript json like the first one?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: You need to read a bit about the difference between JSON (a string) and a Javascript literal object (a piece of Javascript).  They are not the same and you can't just add two of them together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get JSON object from AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217635/get-json-object-from-ajax-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the following line:

```
console.log( "JSON Data: " + json );
```

The code casts the entire object as a string, which is usually not a very useful things as it replaces anything that is an object with this nice [object Object] you're getting.

You could either log the object itself in a separate parameter:

```
console.log( "JSON Data: ", json );
```

Or dump the JSON representation of the object:

```
console.log( "JSON Data: ", JSON.stringify(json));
```

But you'll probably see that your `json` variable is already what you expected.

Comment: Better than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()` function

```
console.log( "JSON Data: " + JSON.stringify(json) );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `"JSON Data: " + json`, you are actually converting the `json` object to a string.

You can use `"JSON Data: " + JSON.stringify(json)` instead.

Comment: It doesn't "*convert*" the json object to a string; it *casts* it. Be careful of your wording, your current post could give the impression that the variable itself is being modified - it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
"JSON Data: " + json
```

Will convert the `json` object into a string which looks like `[object Object]`.

You can just do:

```
console.log( "JSON Data: ", json );
```

to write the object to the console instead of its string representation.